# use a python set to report shells listed in /etc/passwd file

Tags: python, linux, set, etcpasswd

I need to know how to use a python set to list all the unique shells listed in the /etc/passwd file in the linux filesystem. This will be executed in a python shell from the command line.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a python set for this instead of, say, a python dict, or a shell script?

Answer (score 2):

easiest way:

```
import pwd
shells = set(p.pw_shell for p in pwd.getpwall())
print('\n'.join(shells))
```

Comment: +1. Except that he needs to get it printed out, and given the question I'm not sure he can figure that out on his own, so add a `print('\n'.join(shells))` or something at the end.

Comment: @abarnert - good point, although 'to list' doesn't necessarily mean 'to print' ;) but I've added a print anyway...